# Capturing traffic with Wireshark on mirrored port on cisco switch

Tags: switch, wireshark, traffic

My laptop is directly connected to the destination port on the Cisco switch.

When capturing traffic on a cisco switch on destination port of mirrored port with wireshark, does my laptop needs an ip address in the same range with the devices in that network and the same gateway?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for SPAN/RSPAN.

you want your adapter in promiscuous mode/monitor mode. And not engaging in layer-2 or layer-3 traffic.

This should get you going
https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/lan-switching-and-routing/how-do-we-use-wireshark-on-cisco-networks/td-p/1612394